# Determine BSC Sell/BUY Transactions

Tags: blockchain, web3js, binance-smart-chain

Im connecting to BSC websocket with:

```
let options = {
    filter: {
        value: [],
    },
    fromBlock: 0
};

myContract.events.Transfer(options)
    .on('data', event => console.log(event))
    .on('changed', changed => console.log(changed))
    .on('error', err => throw err)
    .on('connected', str => console.log(str))
```

In response on the 'Transfer' event I get the

```
   data  {
  address: 'xxxxx',
  blockNumber: xxx,
  transactionHash: 'xxxx',
  transactionIndex: 17,
  blockHash: 'xxx',
  logIndex: 35,
  removed: false,
  id: 'xx',
  returnValues: Result {
    '0': 'xx',
    '1': 'xx',
    '2': '800000000000000000',
    from: 'xx',
    to: 'xxx',
    value: '800000000000000000'
  },
  event: 'Transfer',
  signature: 'xxx',
  raw: {
    data: 'xxx',
    topics: [
      'xxx',
      'xx',
      'xxx'
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to determine the SELL/BUY transaction. How I can know if this is sell or a buy?

Comment: Each `Transfer` have tow parties, seller and buyer.
Buyer address placed in `to` seller in `from`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find topics of smartcontract events by opening contract in e.g bscscan.

For Example:

https://bscscan.com/address/0x0ed8e0a2d99643e1e65cca22ed4424090b8b7458#events

There you will find logs with "Sync" and "Swap" events.

Sync event topic is: 0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1

Swap event topic is:
0xd78ad95fa46c994b6551d0da85fc275fe613ce37657fb8d5e3d130840159d822